# XSD expression to validate XML with date and time

Tags: regex, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have the following XSD to validate this XML, but I don't know why it says that is valid. Notice that the pattern only checks for date, not date + time. Do you know how can I put a pattern to take only as valid the date + time? Thank you very much in advance.

**XML:**

```
<IN_PARAM>
    <DATE_FROM>20/01/2018 10:35:00</DATE_FROM>
    <DATE_TO>31/12/2019 18:40:00</DATE_TO>
</IN_PARAM>
```

**XSD:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="IN_PARAM">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="DATE_FROM" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                <xs:element name="DATE_TO" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="DATE_FROM">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="DATE_TO">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. You have to define a type, and that type must have the pattern do you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="IN_PARAM">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="DATE_FROM" type="DateTimeType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                <xs:element name="DATE_TO" type="DateTimeType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:simpleType name="DateTimeType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

And of course, if you need it, here is the pattern for `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss`:

```
<xs:pattern value="(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[012])/[0-9]{4} (0[0-9]|[1][0-9]|2[1-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])"/>
```